# code in multiprocessing.pool goes freezed, but works fine through loop or joblib.Parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multiprocessing, scikit-learn

ok, I have the following code:

```
pool    = Pool(worker_amount)
results = pool.imap(task_handler, tasks) 
for result in results:
    do_something(result)

pool.close()
pool.join()
...
```

it never finished.
If I change it to avoid pool, like that:

```
results = []
for task in tasks:
   results.append(task_handler(task))  
for result in results:
   do_something(result)        
...
```

it works in a a moment.

`task_handler` looks similar to that:

```
X = task.X
Y = task.Y
...
fn = LogisticRegression()  #from scikit-learn package
fn.fit(X,Y)
...
```

And the `fit` method is a last point I'm able to achieve in debugger.

Also some important notes: I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/64 Bit, Python 2.7.6 in Virtualenv. IDE - PyCharm, but code also fails if run from terminal. And, bu the way, I trying to run this code with different worker amount from 1 to 4 - not help.

Please, help me to understand an issue there.

**UPD1:** If use joblib.Parallel instead it's also work fine, but it's work more like `map`, is it possible to use it like `imap`

---

There is a gists which reproduce the problem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9994217

Comment: Shouldn't you join before using the results?

Comment: I think it's fine, but even if I move it before using results it's still not working. I expecting it's some kind of a problem related to Ubuntu and pool.

Comment: Yes, this line executed just fine